# How does $X_{n+1 }= (1-10^{4}h)X_n\quad X_n= (1-10^{4}h)^{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How does

$X_{n+1} = (1-10000h)X_n$

become

$X_n= (1-10000h)^{n+1}$

I can't seem to understand the solution to one of my questions because of this transformation of $X_{n+1}$. I'm not sure how the $X_n$ vanishes.

Comment: If you're going to ask a lot of questions here, you owe it to yourself to learn how to format them. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and/or http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $X_n=(1-10000h)^nX_0$.

From $X_{n+1}=(1-10000h)X_n$, letting $n=0$, you get $X_1=(1-10000h)X_0$. Then, letting $n=1$, you get $X_2=(1-10000h)X_1=(1-10000h)^2X_0$. Then, letting $n=2$, you get $X_3=(1-10000h)X_2=(1-10000h)^3X_0$. With any luck, by now you see the pattern, and then you can prove it by induction on $n$.